# get-wmi to delete user profiles by matching the local path attribute

Tags: powershell, csv, get-wmiobject

I am working on a script to audit a server for profiles, determine which belong to users who are disabled in AD and then deleting just those from the server.  I almost have it working but I think the code I am using to actually run the delete is not quite right.  here is the script I have so far:

```
# grabbing name of server we want to run the commands on
$cname = read-host "enter computer name:"
#
#using get-wmi to populate a csv file called paths.csv with the localpath 
info for any user profiles on the server named in $cname
get-wmiobject -class win32_userprofile -computername $cname | select-object 
localpath | where localpath -like "c:\users*" | export-csv paths.csv -
NoTypeInformation
#
#grabbing just the leaf of the local path for each user
$users = Import-Csv paths.csv | ForEach-Object { Split-Path $_.localpath -
leaf } | out-file users.csv
#
#Grabbing the usernames and Asking Active Directory for the status of the 
enabled property for each
$AD = @(gc users.csv | % {Get-ADUser $_ | select samaccountname,enabled})
#
#Exporting ONLY the DISABLED users to a new csv file.
$AD | ? { -not($_.enabled) } | export-csv -notypeinformation disabled.csv
#
#Adding a new column to the disabled csv that recreates the folder path 
based on the username.
import-csv disabled.csv | Select-Object *,@{Name="localpath";Expression=
{"C:\Users\$($_.samaccountname)"}} | export-csv -notypeinformation 
dispaths.csv
#
#using get-wmi to delete any profiles that have a localpath property which 
matches one of the local path fields in the dispaths.csv file
$dispaths = import-csv dispaths.csv
Foreach ($localpath in $dispaths) 
{get-wmiobject -class win32_userprofile -computername $cname | where 
{$_.localpath -eq $localpath} | foreach {$_.Delete()}
}
```

the dispaths.csv file ends up with a column that has the correct data but when the get-wmi command runs at the end, it doesn't actually delete any profiles.  It's like nothing returned by the get-wmi is matching the target I set.  I am sure I have a logical or syntax error but I need a little guidance to find it.

I am trying to have the code look at each field in a column called "localpath" and delete any profiles it finds on the server which have a matching string in their localpath attribute.  when I run the script it just returns a new line but none of the profiles have been removed.

Comment: `where 
{$_.localpath -eq $localpath}` -> `where 
{$_.localpath -eq $localpath.localpath}` Also exporting a csv just to reimport it seems unnecessary. Just save object to a variable, export the variable to csv. Then you can reuse the variable.

Comment: thanks that fixed it.  I am considering breaking it into two scripts so the profiles can be manually reviewed to make certain they are ok to be removed before the delete takes place.  that's why I was exporting it...